# SQL Server Remote Connections

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Remote Connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/220459/sql-server-remote-connections)

I am at my wits end with trying to access a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 Express instance. Here are the following that I have tried.

1) I enabled remote connections in the instance properties.
2) I enabled sql server and windows authentication mode and created an account to log in using sql server authentication.
3) I started the SQL Server Browser service
4) I forwarded ports 1433 and 1434 on the router to the IP address of the machine hosting SQL Server.
5) I turned off firewalls on both the Machine running the instance and the router.
6) http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ I used this to check whether or not both ports were open and it says that they are closed. I have the SQL Server Express instance running and the browser running. I have configured it to allow remote connections yet, it tells me they are both closed. I'm pretty confused at this stage.

On the client Machine I am trying to connect using the following format machineip\SQLEXPRESS with SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart SQL Server after configuring the connection protocols? If not, you need to for those changes to take affect.

Comment: Yes I have restarted SQL Server after every change made. I am just wondering about the TCP/IP settings in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. There are a range of Ip settings i.e. IP1, IP2....IPALL. Perhaps I have settings wrong here. Currently I usued IP4, Active:Yes, Enabled:No, Ip Address:machineip, TCP Dynamic Ports : Blank, TCP Port 1433

Comment: The answer is in your comment. TCP\IP is not enabled. Active and Enabled are two different things. TCP\IP is active but not enabled in your case. You need to set it to enabled and restart SQL Server.

Comment: I enabled it and restarted SQLExpress but still having the same problem. The actual error I get on the remote client is A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Comment: Start with the basics. Can you connect to SQL server from a computer on the same LAN? Does the SQL Server have a default gateway? Can the SQL Server ping other computers on the same LAN? Can the SQL Server ping the default gateway?